# Nash equilibrium in game theory?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, game

Are there examples of the solution of Nash non-cooperative games with mixed or pure strategies? How could be implemented in Mathematica 10?

Comment: If you search the Wolfram library you should find some examples. I recall examples in one or more books by Hal Varian -- the code from which may or may not be in the Wolfram library.

Comment: The Demonstrations project is also worth searching: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=nash